# How to filter on '@' character in a tuple of type (String, Seq(String, String, ...))?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am trying to find all mentionned persons inside tweets. To do so, I need to filter words preceded by '`@`' inside tweets.

I am using Java 8 with Spark 2.4.3.

First thing, I am loading my JSON file as an `RDD[Tweet]` (the exercise specifically asks to work with RDD, not DataFrame).

A Tweet is a case class as follow:

```scala
case class Tweet (
    id : String,
    user : String,
    userName : String,
    text : String,
    place : String,
    country : String,
    lang : String
)
```

Next thing I create pairs (user, tweets), and split words in tweets by " ":

```scala
val tweets = loadData
val persons = tweets.map(row => (row.user, Seq(row.text.split(" ").mkString(","))))
```

Then, I have tried to `flatMap` everything and iterate over all elements to find "@" but I did not succeed.

I expect the results to be as follow:

```
(user1, Seq(@michael, @jean, @paul, @charles))
(user2, Seq(@kol, @louis))
```

Comment: Which error have you encountered during which command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this:

```
//Input tweet data  
   scala> df.show(false)
    +---+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+
    |Id |User    |UserName     |Text                               |Place  |Country|language|
    +---+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+
    |1  |nksuthar|Nikhil Suthar|Good Morning @nikhil and @hardik   |Mumbai |India  |Hindi   |
    |2  |matt    |Mathew       |Welcome @John                      |Paris  |France |English |
    |3  |JohnM   |Johnson      |@Mathew Are you coming with @nguyen|NewYork|US     |English |
    +---+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+

    //Create one UDF to check '@' in Text

    scala> val check_@ = (s:String) => {
                val ss = s.split(" ").filter(x => x.contains("@"))
                ss.toSeq}

    //Register UDF as filtreUDF

    scala> val filterUdf = udf(check_@)

    scala> val newdf  = df.withColumn("new_col", filterUdf(col("Text")))

    /*
    +---+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+------------------+
    |Id |User    |UserName     |Text                               |Place  |Country|language|new_col           |
    +---+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+------------------+
    |1  |nksuthar|Nikhil Suthar|Good Morning @nikhil and @hardik   |Mumbai |India  |Hindi   |[@nikhil, @hardik]|
    |2  |matt    |Mathew       |Welcome @John                      |Paris  |France |English |[@John]           |
    |3  |JohnM   |Johnson      |@Mathew Are you coming with @nguyen|NewYork|US     |English |[@Mathew, @nguyen]|
    +---+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+------------------+
    */
    scala> val finaltpl = newdf.select("User","new_col").rdd.map(x => (x.get(0), x.get(1)))

    scala> finaltpl.foreach(println)
    (matt,WrappedArray(@John))
    (JohnM,WrappedArray(@Mathew, @nguyen))
    (nksuthar,WrappedArray(@nikhil, @hardik))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to filter all the words that starts with @ but have exactly  one @ and then chars

```
val persons = tweets.map(row => (row.user, Seq(row.text.split(" ").filter(_.matches("^@{1}.*")).mkString(","))))
```